Why is cold temperature correction not applied from FAF to MAPt on RNP approaches using LNAV/VNAV minima?
Cold temperature corrections are made to altitudes in the Flight Management Computer (FMC) because, at low temperatures, the altimeter shows a higher altitude than the aircraft's true altitude. For instance, at -10°C, if the aircraft is at 3,000 ft according to the altimeter, the true altitude might actually be 2,800 ft due to the cold temperature causing an underreading of 200 ft.
At the company I fly for (B737s NGs and Max), we apply temperature corrections to altitudes on the approach and missed approach profile for any altitudes below the corrected Minimum Safe Altitude (MSA).
However, company procedures I fly for specify that when flying an RNP approach and using LNAV/VNAV minima, we should not apply temperature corrections to altitudes between the Final Approach Fix (FAF) and the Missed Approach Point (MAPt), though we are required to correct the Decision Altitude (DA). If we are flying the approach using only LNAV minima, then the Minimum Descent Altitude (MDA) is temperature corrected, with an additional 40 ft added. Moreover, when only LNAV minima is used, all altitudes below the MSA are temperature corrected.
What is the rationale behind this? Why would it be inappropriate to apply temperature corrections between the FAF and MAPt when using LNAV/VNAV minima (a 3D approach)? What is different about an approach that uses only LNAV minima (a 2D approach)?

My question differs from the existing ones as it focuses on why cold temperature corrections aren’t applied from the FAF to MAPt when using LNAV/VNAV minima and how this differs from LNAV minima procedures.
We do not currently operate RNP AR (Authorisation Required) approaches or those using LPV (Localiser Performance with Vertical Guidance).

They are not applied because the allowed temperature range is included in procedure design. That means the Final Approach Segment (FAS) is protected down to what is called the Promulgated Minimum Temperature. The lowest allowable OAT reads somewhere in the notes as "Baro-VNAV N/A below -15C" or something similar.
The APV Baro-VNAV allowes for 75 ft deviation below glideslope and this includes temperature corrections down to the promulgated temperature as indicated in the chart. If OAT is below ISA, the actual flight path will be lower and glide angle will be shallower than indicated in the chart but required obstacle clearances will be satisfied.
If FMS compensates for temperature, as described in Bianfable's answer, this temperature limitation does not apply (of course, as described in your company manuals)
The procedure design in different types of RNP approaches is different although they are described on the same chart. While the vertical profile for 2D approach with LNAV minima is similar to other 2D approaches such as VOR, the 3D APV Baro-VNAV does not have any stepdown fixes or MDA. If they are drawn to the chart, they only apply when flying to LNAV minimums.
This is further complicated by the guidance method used. At least in Airbus it is allowed to fly the 2D approach (ie. LNAV minimums) using the same 3D guidance as Baro-VNAV. When doing so, all the stepdown fixes and MDA will apply and must be monitored from the chart by the crew during the approach.

This sounds like you are flying a compensated baro VNAV approach, where the FMC provides compensation for temperature effects automatically and therefore does not require the pilot to correct altitudes manually.

RNAV instrument approach procedures use barometric altitudes and barometric vertical navigation (Baro VNAV) in the approach design. As a result, true altitude can differ greatly when temperatures become extremely hotter or colder than standard. [...]
Honeywell NZ6.1, EPIC, APEX/ACE, and NG FMS all have a temperature compensation (temp comp) capability. This function provides temperature compensated VNAV altitudes during operations in extremely hot or cold temperatures. Temp comp raises the waypoint altitude constraint values in cold weather and lowers the waypoint altitude constraint values in hot weather. The FMS adjusts the altitudes for all the waypoints in the approach and missed approach segments of the flight plan, ensuring the aircraft is at the published true altitudes.

(Honeywell: Inside the FMS)
This function is independent of barometric minima, which need to be adjusted manually:

A separate input is necessary to adjust the DA / MDA, since it is not automatically compensated for temperature.

(Honeywell: Inside the FMS)
On the Boeing 737 NG this feature is available since FMC Update 14 released in September 2019:

U14 features:

[...] VNAV temperature compensation gives the ability to semi-automatically adjust the procedure barometric altitude constraints and glide path angles based on a pilot-entered temperature, so the FMS descent path can account for the effects of temperature. [...]


(b737.org.uk: FMC Update 14)
If installed, there should be TEMP COMP REF page on APPROACH REF page 3 as shown here:

(YouTube: 737 FMC U11 to U14.1)
